# Website redirect to same page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

My website having error with all pages redirecting to same page in worddpress only home page is working perfectly.But when we click on any page it redirect to course detail page but the url of that page is same as show on click.

My Website is http://www.trayn.com.au/

Answer (score 0):

After set up your wordpress project. Can you save your Permalinks changes from setting menu ?